# Type incompatibility for subclass' decorated method - python

Tags: python, properties, python-decorators, mypy, type-hinting

I'm getting an error

```
$ mypy python.py
python.py:34: error: Signature of "fn" incompatible with supertype "B"
```

where python.py is

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar('T')


def dec(f: Callable[..., T]) -> T:
    def p(self):
        return getattr(self, '_' + f.__name__)

    return cast(T, property(p))


class X:
    pass


class Y(X):
    pass


class A:
    _fn = Y()


class B(A):
    @dec
    def fn(self) -> X:
        return X()


class C(B):
    @dec
    def fn(self) -> Y:
        return Y()
```

Here, the decorator `dec` is meant to do two things

- promote the corresponding method to a property
- redirect the call to an attribute whose name has an additional underscore

I don't understand why mypy can't work out that Y inherits from X. There's no error if I replace `-> Y` with `-> X`, or if I remove the decorators.

I've tried this with mypy 0.630 and Python 3.5.2, 3.6.6 and 3.7.0

**EDIT** As pointed out in the comments, the type of `A._fn` as originally posted wasn't compatible with `C.fn`. I've edited `A._fn` to remove this problem. The error has not changed.

**EDIT** some context - `A` is a configuration schema class that looks more like

```
class A:
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         for k, v in kwargs.items():
             setattr(self, '_' + k, v)
```

and we expect users to use it like `c = C(fn=Y()); c.fn # gives a Y`. Originally the question had `A_.fn` as a *method* that returned `Y()`. Correcting this didn't affect the error

**EDIT** I've raised this as a mypy bug https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5836

Comment: Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I run this... can you show the full command you use to run the file? What version of python & mypy are you using?

Comment: My bad. I was calling it wrong. I got the same as you.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth tbh I removed `--strict` as it wasn't necessary for the error

Comment: `Y` is not `X`.

Comment: @StephenRauch can you elaborate? (I've added a note that on removing the decorators the error ceases)

Comment: So what would it *mean* here? You replaced a function that promises to return `Y`, with an object that returns `X` instead. You *limited* the return value. Anyone calling `C().fn()` can reasonably expect to be able to use `Y()` methods and attributes, but `X()` would not have those. This breaks the contract you stated `fn()` to have. I'd normally point to [*covariance and contravariance*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) here but you can't use contravariance on return values precisely because you can't just cut away functionality like this.

Comment: Put differently, why should Mypy allow a transformation from `Y` to `X` happen via a decorator, when that decorator promised to return the exact same type? `dec` takes a `Callable` that returns `T`, and produces `T` as a result. `Y` -> `X` does not match that signature, and there is no *sane* path from `Y` to `X` that won't lose functionality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you make a good point, though I've found that altering the return type and value of `A()._fn` to Y and Y() (which I believe addresses your concern) doesn't fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant that dec will return a Callable and not T.
It should be:

```
def dec(f: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[..., T]:
    def p(self):
       return getattr(self, '_' + f.__name__)

    return cast(Callable[..., T], property(p))
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on this, but I don't think it's a `Callable[..., T]`. It should be a `property`, but since anywhere it's called this syntactically has the same type as a T, we can safely cast to T